# How to expand command-mode abbreviations in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have defined several abbreviations for command and insert-mode, e.g.:

```
ca selforg :e d:\projects\org\self-org.md
```

I know that I can list them with `:ab`

Is it possible to expand the example by typing `self<tab>` to `selforg` as it is possible for built-in or plugin commands?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible.

Comment: Commands can be expanded. Command-abbrevtions, i don't remember.  Otherwise in insert mode only snippets may what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List them with `:ab`; restrict the list with `:ab s<Tab>`

So, if you type `:ab self<tab>` this expands to `selforg`.

If you have similar named abbreviations the menu will show all your possible resolutions.

If you need to "tab complete and auto commit" your abbreviations, see this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7750/how-do-i-manage-and-remember-many-abbreviations-in-my-vimrc